# Distribution platforms for Android app bundle for CICD

Tags: android, continuous-deployment, software-distribution, hockeyapp

I see Google has come up with new packaging format for Android apps, App Bundle. You can upload bundles on Google Play Console in various tracks to proceed testing and build distribution. This sounds good.

However, if you are using apps like Hockey for local distribution of your app within your organization(CICD built). Is there any such distribution platforms other than Google Play that supports bundle upload?

Thanks in advance!